# Conditional boolean type in typescript with interface

Tags: typescript

How would I write conditional boolean type for this?

i.e

```
export interface Props {
  editable: boolean;
  position: { editable: true } ? Sheets.Matrix : never;
  value: string;
  classNames?: string;
  textType?: "bold" | "editing" | "normal";
  onChange?: (val: Sheets.SaveData) => void;
}
```

I use props like this

```
const SheetsCell: React.FC<MainProps> = ({
  editable,
  value,
  textType = "normal",
  classNames = "",
  position,
  ...
```

Here if something is editable, I want the type of position to be `Sheets.Matrix` else, position isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is using an interface and the intersection operator(`&`).

You can use an [intersection type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types), which combines multiple types into one.

```
interface Props {
  value: string;
  classNames?: string;
  textType?: "bold" | "editing" | "normal";
  onChange?: (val: number) => void;
}

type MainProps = Props & {
  editable: true;
  position: number; 
} | Props & {
  editable: false;
  position?: number; 
};
```

The above type `MainProps` forces `editable` to be `true` in one case and `false` in another. If `editable` is `true`, then position property exists and if it is `false,` position property exists but it is not required.

[unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) is used above, to generate a type  which can be one of the two values.
`MainProps` can be one of the two types (both being intersection with `Props` type).

Here is the [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=14&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOyDeAUMsgG5wA2ArhAFzI5hSgDmA3McghXDjgHJwAthBwB+eo2Yh2nSAA8wAFQCeWCBOQAiAEYYKAEy3IAPtogHgYVsbNaQGKEMpaOJDCADCACzgyN9AAU5BT0IFRCOtAAlMgAvAB8ZBjABhwAvoSEYGooALJwoOjYeHFomLjIAGQEhBZWcDoUdMhMNBxYGDhWwB5hEVFQbMiE6ablJdW19WCNzfTwFDgQHV09HprhkdDDoyOECB6MyFYQQgCMyPQFRRWltZwhNPQA5N7ALwA0nDNzLW0Qb6dbrWPrIABMI3SHCyhxAx1OQkh10KIGKlTKREelGeyDeH2+JF+TRai2WQLWoJA9EhoxhcIRkCEAGYrsgbmi7vEHiQni18V9CMD1tSIVC2EA)

Comment: Thanks, Small correction, I think for `Props & {
editable: false;
} 
` you need to add `position?: undefined` else typescript throws error

Comment: Ok I missed that part. `position` is allowed but it can be optional is it?

Comment: Updated the question: So, Yeah, I de-structure (as in now question).

Comment: You can just do `Props & ({ editable: false } | { editable: true, position: number })`

Comment: thanks @Nullndr, you can edit the answer if you feel like. Or i can add it. This is a good tip.

Answer (score 1):

You could use type aliases instead of an interface e.g.

```
type Props = { 
  editable: true;
  position: Sheets.Matrix;
} | { 
  editable: false;
};

const testFalse: Props = { // position not required
  editable: false
}
    
const testTrue: Props = { // position mandatory
  editable: true,
  position: MatrixEnum
}
```